# Why does this for loop containing a delay not run to completion?

Tags: verilog

I have two test benches:

```
// test_a.v
module test_a;
    initial
    begin
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) begin
            $display("hello");
            #10;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

```
// test_b.v
module test_b;
    initial
    begin
        #50;
        $finish();
    end
endmodule
```

I build and run this like so:

```
iverilog -g2012 -o icarus.out test_a.v test_b.v
vvp icarus.out
```

...and then see this output:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

But it stops there. Why do I not get 128 "hello"s? I guess the `$finish()` in `test_b.v` causes `test_a.v` to quit early but is that expected?

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/JjJR

Comment: @dave_59 - I think you're right - I have another test bench which does `$finish()` which seems to be what's causing the problem. Does that sound plausible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a problem with a piece of code you have not shown. Adding a final block after the initial block might give some clues.

```
final $display($realtime);
```

It is unfortunate that Icarus Verilog does not notify you that it has hit a `$finish` and just prints `Done`. So you might wanna search for other `$finish` tasks and put a `$display` statement just before it.

### UPDATE:

Based on your updated code, all modules share the same global concept of simulation time, beginning and end-of-time. When one module executes a `$finish`, that is the end-of-time for the entire simulation. The way you have coded it, there is a race condition whether you would see 5 or 6 "hello"s.

Comment: Adding `final $display($realtime);` to `test_a.v` outputs `50` which would seem to confirm that it's the `$finish()` from the other module which is causing `test_a` to quit early. Is that expected behaviour though in verilog?

I have a feeling the `$finish()` shouldn't be necessary anyway in my real code - I may have to submit another question about that...